# TypeError: Member "expectEmit" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Vm

Tags: solidity, testing, solidity-0.8.x, unittesting, foundry

This is the error in all of the tests in which I am expecting an emit, been struggling with this since many days, any help would really be appreciated.

I also tried creating events in a new contract and still got this particular error.

vm.prank works, vm.expectRevert and other vm functions work too but only the .expectEmit function causes an error.

Code for the test

```
function testCanSubmitTransaction() public {
        vm.prank(owner1);
        vm.expectEmit(true);
        emit Submit(0);
        multisig.submit(address(owner2), 1 ether, "");
    }
```

Code of the Submit function

```
function submit(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes calldata _data
    ) public onlyOwner {
        transactions.push(
            Transaction({to: _to, value: _value, data: _data, executed: false})
        );
        emit Submit(transactions.length - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently .expectEmit() takes in 4  bool arguments and/or an address (this code is from Vm.sol)

```
function expectEmit(bool,bool,bool,bool) external;
function expectEmit(bool,bool,bool,bool,address) external;
```

So adding 3 extra `false` to my code works!

Fixed Code:

```
function testCanSubmitTransaction() public {
        vm.prank(owner1);
        vm.expectEmit(true, false, false, false);
        emit Submit(0);
        multisig.submit(address(owner2), 1 ether, "");
    }
```

TOOK ME 2 DAYS! ‍

Comment: Actually, your answer is not complete since the question does not make it clear whether the parameter in the `Submit` event is indexed or not. If the parameter is indexed, then your answer is correct. If not, then the `vm.expectEmit` params need to be set to `vm.expectEmit(false, false, false, true);`. Full explanation is available in the docs: https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/cheatcodes

Comment: Actually, this answer was really helpful to me even now almost a year and half later after this question was asked.

Events can have a up to a max of three indexable events and the fourth parameter specifies whether or not to check the data. Writing docs is hard and I think the docs could be improved with more examples to better clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the user's original problem, but results in the same error message:

If you want to use `expectRevert(MyCustomError)`, you have to use `expectRevert(MyCustomError.selector)`, instead. You get this error because the compiler goes looking for an implementation of `function expectRevert(Error error)`, but there is no such implementation. The call `expectRevert(MyCustomError.selector)` instead invokes `function expectRevert(bytes4 errorSelector)`.